# Displaying Twitter feed stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, feed

The default way to display a twitter feed has stopped working. Here is an example code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        The feed should display below:
        <div id="twitter_update_list"> </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/stackoverflow.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=4">
    </body>
</html>
```

**Why is this not working?** I suspected that the issue was on Twitter's end but this has not functioned for a while now. I created a fiddle in case you want to play: http://jsfiddle.net/9EvXn/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to update your code to Twitter's new API. This code will work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
 <div id="twitter_update_list"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=stackoverflow&include_rts=true&count=4&callback=twitterCallback2"></script>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Pay attention to this line of code that is updated:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=stackoverflow&include_rts=true&count=4&callback=twitterCallback2
```

Comment: This fixed my error for now, although it will only work until March 2013! Twitter says
API 1.0 will cease accepting requests six months from when API v1.1 is released. We will officially turn off the endpoints for API v1.0 on March 5th, 2013. [https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#10647](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#10647)

Comment: Are you saying that this solution will not work from March: http://jsfiddle.net/9EvXn/4/ Please elaborate on your answer Mark.

Comment: That's what I understand from the info from Twitter via the link I posted.

Comment: they had a channel to warn everyone about the API to become obsolete and did not used it ... sigh.

Answer (score 3):

Someone recently wrote this on my blog (as a comment to an article on displaying Twitter feeds):

> Just a heads up, if you are using this code I've noticed that it stopped working recently. I believe it is due to Twitter's new API. The culprit is the url that fetches the tweets. here is an updated url that seems to fix the issue:
>   `var url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=' + username + '&count=' + limit + '&callback=?';`

So perhaps just slap "api" in front of "twitter.com". And the /1/ I assume is a version number.

Edit: Apparently this was correct :P

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>
<div id="twitter_update_list"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=stackoverflow&include_rts=true&count=4&callback=twitterCallback2"></script>
```

Comment: It does not seem to work, maybe I made the adjustment incorrectly, check this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9EvXn/1/

Comment: I tried in the fiddle. Didn't work for me either :/ Pretty useless answer from me I guess.

Comment: No it is not useless. Maybe this can shed some light: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAddTweetsToYourBlogAndDebuggingBasicJavaScriptWhyDidTwittercomJavaScriptBloggerJSONPWidgetStopWorking.aspx

Comment: Okay I fixed the stupid thing. You where correct in your answer. Please check the fiddle and paste the code in your answer and I will accept it as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

looks ok to me.

here, i created a jsfiddle to test: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/ULZBB/

try editing my jsfiddle, and see if it can help you.

Comment: Yes I managed to resolve this stupid thing with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/9EvXn/4/

Comment: There must be millions of sites out there without a working display of feed. As most sites are using my version of code... :)

Comment: @ayjay of course it doesn's work anymore. it's a two years old answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of Twitter's latest API updates, announced previously (see https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-housekeeping and https://dev.twitter.com/docs/deprecations/spring-2012).

All calls must now be made the API.twitter.com and using the versionned endpoint (/1.1 ideally, or /1 until March 2012).

Comment: Announced to a degree where no one knows about it.