# Twitter feed on website not working on iPad, iPhone and similar

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, twitter, feed

I'm having trouble viewing the twitter feed [here](http://dev.applications.3d4medical.com/homepage) when trying on iPad, iPhone and I believe any IOS device.

On this post [Displaying Twitter feed stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845545/displaying-twitter-feed-stopped-working) it says that the twitter feed I'm using will be deprecated on March 2013.

The thing is, I don't have any problem seeing my tweets on desktop browser. They only fail in ios.

Any suggestion? Is there anything I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using Adobe Flash which is not supported neither by iPhone, iPad or iOs simulator.

Comment: But it used to work before and I didn't have any problem until now. Why is that then?

Comment: I can't tell how it was working, I can see it uses Flash now.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know it is possible to see that. Then, is there any other way to display the twitter feeds on a website for ios devices now? Most of our traffic comes from those device.

Comment: It's easy to check as you can disable Flash. As for alternatives, there's an API description which I believe do not require any usage of Flash.

Comment: Weird, when I disable flash on Firefox and Safari my tweets keep on appearing. I'm not quite sure they use flash for it. I also tried to find an alternative to my twitter feed but Im not happy with the one the embedded timeline twitter offers.

Comment: Restart Firefox after you disable Flash plugin, try any plugin for Safari to do the same. The page fails to display feed to me with Flash being disabled agains both browsers, the feed is shown when Flash is enabled though.